# PYTHON SELENIUM: Switching to IFRAME with Java built in

Tags: javascript, python, iframe, web-scraping

I believe the best way for me to access an IFRAME is to switch into it, however I believe there are issues on this switch (I believe I am doing this right).  My ultimate objective is to search the parent website, then "click" on the "Individual Ranking" which is in an IFRAME.  From this, I want to load the source after clicking to get the actual data table.  Can someone please assist me to click on the "Individual Ranking" so that I can obtain the data table.

Link:[Road Ranking](http://www.uci.ch/road/ranking/)

In this you will see a screenshot, the highlighted is what I am trying to navigate to, load and return the data table after it loads.
[image: Shows the Link I am trying to Click On]

Here is the code which I have been working with to navigate, however, a printing of the page source does not seem to contain the information I want to navigate too.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url='http://www.uci.ch/road/ranking'
browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='fill me out')
browser.get(url)
element=browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
browser.switch_to.default_content()
print(browser.page_source)
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone reads this and finds that linking directly to an embedded IFRAME is bad practice please let me know, otherwise it did work...

I was able to link directly to the IFRAME's embedded in the website by using the following dictionary:

`urls={
      'UCI World Ranking':['https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RankingDetails/1?disciplineId=10&groupId=1&momentId=19264&disciplineSeasonId=19&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0'],
      'UCI World Tour':['https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RankingDetails/7?disciplineId=10&groupId=3&momentId=19291&disciplineSeasonId=19&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0'],
      'UCI Africa Tour':['https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RankingDetails/2?disciplineId=10&groupId=7&momentId=19265&disciplineSeasonId=19&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0'],
      'UCI American Tour':['https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RankingDetails/3?disciplineId=10&groupId=8&momentId=19266&disciplineSeasonId=19&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0'],
      'UCI Asia Tour':['https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RankingDetails/4?disciplineId=10&groupId=9&momentId=19267&disciplineSeasonId=19&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0'],
      'UCI Europe Tour':['https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RankingDetails/5?disciplineId=10&groupId=10&momentId=19268&disciplineSeasonId=19&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0'],
      'UCI Oceania Tour':['https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RankingDetails/6?disciplineId=10&groupId=11&momentId=19269&disciplineSeasonId=19&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0']
      }`